# Type id to the left or right of var id?

Tags: syntax, language-design, compiler-construction

What is the reasoning behind the two common variable declaration syntax that many popular languages use, such as:
      int foo = 0;
and
      foo:int = 0;

One problem I have with the second option, is that it almost looks like you are doing, "int = 0;".  Why do languages use a particular way? Is it easier to parse or something of the like?

Comment: This is very subjective.

Comment: Discussion isn't on topic here. I'm not voting to close yet as an objective summary of pros and cons apart from "looks good to me" may be possible.

Comment: I know it is subjective, which is why im looking for actual reasoning rather than just preference or what looks better. Is one easier to parse? Does one carry more consistence when applied to function/class syntax as well? Ect ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have studied the basics of compiler development and I do not think that parsers have any problem at all in both cases given actual solutions and techniques.

For me it's clearly a matter of readability from human eyes. I think it's easier to read

`int foo = 0`

than

`foo:int = 0`

In fact, I would say that it's even easier to simply write `foo = 0`, since one can recognize that `0` is an integer number :) I personally like this approach, instead of having type identifiers.